# FB iOS SDK 3.2: Why do I need an access token for logging a conversion pixel?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-insights, facebook-ads-api

I'm trying to log a conversion pixel with Facebook SDK iOS 3.2 by calling

```
[FBInsights logConversionPixel:<pixelID> valueOfPixel:0]
```

Now...

I'm doing this before I know the user logged in with facebook, so it's not certain I have an active FBSession with a user access token to this app.

In result I get the following error:

```
{
        code = 100;
        message = "(#100) Graph API for app id <appID> called, but token has app id 0";
        type = OAuthException;
}
```

If the user logs in to facebook and then log the conversion, everything works fine.

The thing I don't get is why do a logging of a conversion pixel needs to happen from an authorized session, in the php code of the app I can simply go to `https://www.facebook.com/offsite_event.php?id=<pixelID>&amp;value=0` without any access token and it will mark my conversion pixel.

Any thoughts/ideas of how can use FBInsights without an active session?

Answer (score 0):

If this problem still actual (maybe will actual for someone), then you can try set Client token for FBSettings class

```
[FBSettings setClientToken:@"<your app client token>"];
```

You can get client token on your app settings page - Advanced - Security section. There should be checkpoint "Client token" that set to OFF. Just set it ON and save changes, then you get client token